# How fix error "no such file to load -- RMagick"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rmagick

After upgrading to Rails 3.0 Library rmagick longer be detected. Here is my setup:

```
Ubuntu server 10.4
gem 1.7.2
ruby 1.9.1
rails 3.0.7
rmagick-2.13.1
```

In irb can include library:

```
irb(main):002:0> require 'RMagick'
=> true
```

In rails 2 rmagick is available.

Comment: You should really be running ruby 1.9.2

Comment: A clarification to flOOr's answer - It appears that the gem file names are case sensitive. I had to enter: gem 'rmagick' in my Gemfile before the `bundle install` command would work.

Comment: Also remember to restart the rails server

Answer (score 15, accepted):

add

```
gem 'RMagick'
```

or

```
gem "rmagick", "~> 2.13.1"
```

to your `Gemfile` and then run

```
bundle
```

Comment: ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'RMagick' (>= 0) in any repository

Answer (score 5):

install

```
apt-get install libmagick9-dev
```

first

Answer (score 3):

For those using Heroku:

```
gem "rmagick", "~>2.13.2", :require => 'RMagick'
```

Also, include the following wherever you're using it:

```
require 'RMagick'
```

Comment: this is the best solution, as it does not require a manual `gem install rmgaick`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone reading this now, I was having issues installing `libmagick9-dev`(it appears to have been replaced).

I ran the following and it installed successfully:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-dev
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
gem install rmagick
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When running bundle for an application like Redmine, gem might be optional, so you must include it like:

```
bundle install --with rmagick
```

Considering that it exists in your Gemfile, it should look something
like:

```
  group :rmagick do
    gem "rmagick", "~> 2.16.0"
  end
```